# Swift 5 Error: 'UIImage' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-extensions

When I try to create a UIImage extension in Swift 5, like this:

```
extension UIImage {  
}
```

I get this error:

```
'UIImage' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
```

What causes this and how do I avert it?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you imported UIKit?

Comment: Yes, with no effect.

Comment: If you have multiple modules, compiler gets confused for lookup. Can you make sure that your file is lying in project directory? Go to File Inspector -> Target -> File is checked with tick arrow. Or try putting this extension in some different class you are currently trying.

Comment: I find it odd that it you `extend UIImage` but get an error for `UUImage`... check spelling?

Comment: I corrected the spelling.  The file is checked in the File Inspector

Comment: Did you try putting this in a separate file?

Comment: Yes, it keeps happening.

Comment: @spaine - Is this in a `.swift` file? Does this happen if you try it in a new project?

Comment: Yes, it is a .swift file.  The same error pops up in every .swift file in this project.  It does not happen in other projects.

Comment: @spaine - is your project a mix of Swift and Obj-C? Are you importing some other Frameworks?

Comment: Yes, there are some Objective-C files.

Comment: @spaine - you mentioned in a comment below *"'import UIKit', the word UIKit had a strikethrough"* ... that generally indicates that UIKit has already been imported in that context. So it sounds like you have some conflict related to the Obj-C files... may not be easy to find. You *might* get some help with the **'UIImage' is ambiguous** issue by researching `import uikit shown with strikethrough`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in 3 Swift files at the end of my code:

```
class UIImage {
    private func newBorderMask(_ borderSize: Int, size: CGSize) -> CGImageRef? {
    } 
}
```

So I saw that the code was redeclaring `class UIImage` after the `extension UIImage`.  In each case, I moved the `private func` into the `extension UIImage` and removed the `class UIImage` from the code.  This removed all of the `'UIImage' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context` errors throughout my project.

Comment: As a side note, this entire project was converted from Objective-C to Swift using the Swiftify app.  Most of the code seems to have translated, but there is a lot of clean up of code that did not translate well.

Answer (score -2):

You need

```
import UIKit
```

at the top of the file

Comment: make sure you're spelling it right?  The only reason UIImage could be ambiguous is if you're not importing UIKit

Comment: I imported UIKit.  As I was typing 'import UIKit', the word UIKit had a strikethrough.

Comment: Are you in a playground or a project?